# nginix change root directory if location = something

Tags: nginx

Hi guys i need a little help, with nginx configuration.
So my problem is that i don't want to have phpmyadmin in my website root directory.
Now my nginx.conf looks:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name 192.168.21.177;
   charset utf-8;

   access_log /dev/null main;
   error_log /dev/null;

   root /home/web/wesite1;

    location / {
        index index.php;
    }   
    location /phpmyadmin/ {
       root /home/web/phpmyadmin;
       index index.php;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
       include fastcgi_params;
   }

   location ~ /\.ht {
       deny all;
   }
}
```

But it's not working.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a nested `location` block to run PHP scripts from different document roots.

```
location ^~ /phpmyadmin/ {
    root /home/web;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

So you have two `location ~ \.php$` blocks, one for each document root.

*Note: I think `root` should be `/home/web` inside the `location ^~ /phpmyadmin/` block, which will point to files located in `/home/web/phpmyadmin/`, as the document root and URI are concatenated and `/phpmyadmin` is already part of the URI.*

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for location syntax.